# How to set specific height for different sets of dynamic bootstrap carousel image containers when they load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootstrap-carousel

this is my first question on stackoverflow because I really can't find a solution elsewhere. I really hope any tech-genius can help me here.

I am currently creating an instagram-like website where it loads a lot of images. Some are single and others are multiple images, and they are presented using Bootstrap's carousel. So far everything works fine except for the height. Right now I am hard coding the `.item` class to a height of `750px`, and that is the maximum height I want. But any image of a height less than that will create a blank space on top and bottom of the container. I am wondering is there anyway to detect each set's images' max-height, and apply the height to its container. I have tried using jQuery to select each image set's image maximum height but I am not getting any correct value. Or, is there any better way to solve this issue?

All I want is that short images take up only their short height in its container. If a set of images have different height, the maximum image height will be set as the container's height. Sorry if I cause any confusion, but I hope I am clear on my question. Thanks!

[image]

This is part of my HTML code:

```
<div id='myCarousel$id' class='carousel' data-interval='false'>
    ...
    <div class='carousel-inner postedImage' id='carousel-inner$id'>
        <div class='item active'>
            <img src='$path' />
        </div>
        <div class='item'>
            <img src='$path' />
        </div>
         .....
    </div>
    ...
```

CSS:

```
.postedImage {

    width: 600px;
    max-height:750px;
}

.item {

    height:750px;

}

.item img {

    height: auto;
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;

}
```

NOTE: I use position absolute to prevent different height images bounce up and down when sliding between one another. Top, right, bottom, left is use to crop images larger than 750px in all direction, rather than just cropping from bottom.
The .item is the part to set the height for each image. But it has to take real values, if I set to auto or %, no image will appear.

So how can I append different px to the ".item" class based on the images' max height in each set?

If i use jQuery to look for each image set's max height, is it going to adjust every image set's container's height in time? I mean because they are so many images. Even if I do it in `$(document).ready(function)`, is it going to efficiently do the adjustment once those images load in browser? If no, may I know is there any other option to solve my problem?

Any help will be much appreciated!